Proving monotonicity in ratios of number of partitions with constraints
$\eta(s,n,m)$ counts the number of unordered partitions of $s$ with at most $n$ parts, each of size at most $m$:
$$
\eta(s,n,m)=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if }s>nm\vee s<0\\
1&\text{if }s=nm\\
\eta(s,n,m-1)+\eta(s-m,n-1,m)&\text{o.w.}
\end{cases}
$$
With a shorthand notation $\eta_c(s,n):=\eta(s,n,c)$, I aim to prove the lemma:
$$
s_L+2\le s_R\Rightarrow \frac{\eta_c(s_L,n+1)}{\eta_c(s_L,n)}\le\frac{\eta_c(s_R,n+1)}{\eta_c(s_R,n)}.
$$
Intuitively, first, it is natural that ${\eta_c(s,n)}\le{\eta_c(s,n+1)}$ since we have more flexibility to partition $s$ with a larger $n$ in $\eta_c(s,n)$; also, with a larger $s$, we'd expect the number of partitions to grow faster as $n$ increases, which supports the lemma. However, it is rather unclear to me how to formulate a rigorous proof. Any help would be appreciated.

What numbers are you getting for $c=3, n=4, s_L=5, s_R=6$? I'm getting $\frac{5}{4} > \frac{6}{5}$. And other exceptions too (although all of them seem to have $s_R = s_L+1$). Or did I mess up with the parameters? I did check with this Sage code Partitions(s, max_length=n, max_part=c).cardinality()

@ploosu2 You're right. It seems there should be a stronger condition $s_L+2\le s_R$. I'll see where I messed up.

@ploosu2 I'm running a program to check if there is a counterexample with the stronger condition, but it hasn't found any yet. The lemma is part of solving another question. It still helps with the stronger condition although some corner cases now have to be addressed. Thank you for pointing out the error.
